# How to let Apache send 500 in case of PHP error?

Tags: php, apache, error-handling, http-headers, http-status-codes

I'm developing a PHP application that uses HTTP response codes for communication as well as response bodies. So this is a typical scenario in the PHP code:

```
try {
    doSomething();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
}
```

... and the typical code in clients looks like:

```
switch(responseCode) {
     case 200 :
         // all fine
         // ....
     case 500 :
         // trouble!
 }
```

This is cool, as long as every error is well caught in PHP code.

The problem: If, for any reason in the php code occures an uncaught error **or an uncatchable error like syntax errors**, Apache will send 200 OK. But I wan't apache to say 500 Internal Server Error. Maybe per .htaccess or so.

Comment: Had once a javascript client in mind. Removed the tag.

Comment: Sorry, updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, of course, [write your own error handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). However, not all PHP errors are catchable. For instance, a syntax error won't even allow your code to run, including your error handler.

To handle catchable errors, you can use the [auto_append_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file) and [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directives to place your error handling code code.

Non-catchable errors are a different issue. If PHP runs as [Fast CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html), it will automatically generate a 500 status code for you. However, you're probably running PHP through some other SAPI (such as Apache module). No idea about that, sorry. (I'll report back if I find something.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! 

Yes I wrote a custom error- and exception handler, but you are right, the uncatchable errors are the problem. I'm googling on this..

Comment: Whatever, it's sort of uncommon that such kind of fatal errors go live unnoticed, isn't it?

Comment: syntax errors and other fatal errors can't be caught by any error handler

Answer (score 2):

Response headers are not sent until PHP *echoes* the first byte of response body. You can change headers (and the status code) in the mean time. Keeping that in mind, here is a solution:

Set your script to send a `500` response code at the beginning of script and `200` at the end. Here is an example:

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error');

if (rand(0, 1) == 1) {
    die("Script terminated prematurely");
}

header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 200 OK');
echo "Success";
```

Just ensure that `200` response code is set at only one location in your code.

Note: you can use [`http_response_code`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) (PHP >= 5.4) instead of [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: Nice idea +1 :) But it will still send 200 OK if for example a (fatal) syntax error is thrown.

Comment: At least on PHP >= 5.3.19 a script with syntax errors generates 500 error. No one would like to have such a script on a production server anyway.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Nowadays it's no more a problem - since 5.3 PHP learned at last to send 503 on error, not 200</s>

Err, it seems it was [5.2.4](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.2.4):

> Changed error handler to send HTTP 500 instead of blank page on PHP errors.

You need to set `display_errors = off` to make it work

I have the exact behavior on my windows Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.4.5

Comment: I've tested with PHP 5.3.10. A syntax error for example will still result in an 200 OK. Under which circumstances will PHP send the 503?

Comment: Your update sounds great!! But it is still not working for me. I've tested with PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4. I used a simple syntax error page `<? error` for testing. `display_errors` is disabled. I still get a blank page and response code 200. I'm using the apache2 sapi. Do you know a php version / web server combination with that you can produce the 500 ?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, do there exist ways to temporary override the 5.2.4 behavior, forcing it to show a blank page on PHP errors?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, `display_errors` is 0 and the page is sending HTTP 500. can we override this behavior, forcing it to show a blank page instead?

Comment: @Pacerier PHP **does** show a blank page. Whatever else decorations you may see, provided by either browser (most likely as most of them like to) or a web-server (needs a special tuning though). Try to request your page with a command-line agent like `wget` and see

Comment: @YourCommonSense, sorry for not being clear. I mean override the HTTP 500 behavior, forcing it to show a HTTP 200 blank page instead?