# PHP Error Handling, when the error is a text message instead of a thrown Exception

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

So, I just started some PHP development for the first time. I am trying to use a HTML DOM navigation/parsing library. I picked ganon, but do not really care which one I end up using.

But I have noted right away that PHP is fundamentally different than all other coding languages I have ever seen. And this is very obvious when I look at error handling. If an included class/script just prints its error I cannot simple catch it with a try/catch. Which I believe is what is happening here. I do not have control, even though I am the one who told file_get_dom to run. It can do whatever it wants and write whatever it wants to the resulting HTML file.

Is this bad practice, it sure is screwing me up. What is the solution? Can I catch the text it tries to write (surround it with a hidden div)? But, at the same time that I want to stop this class from writing whatever it wants, I also what to know if an error happened so I can take the appropriately steps.

NOTE: Doing more tests, even when I throw my own errors or using "or die" it is not doing what I would expect, exactly. So maybe I also just have no idea how to use Try/Catch, even though I have seen it used in a few tutorials exactly like this. But my original questions remains even if this is a syntax error, how to control included classes so they do not pollute my html file.

```
<?php
try{
 include_once('ganon.php');
}catch(Exception $e){ echo  "OUT: $e->getMessage()"; }

class GamesSummery{
  public function __construct(){

    try{
        $html = file_get_dom('web site adress');
    }catch(Exception $e){ echo "Main: $e->getMessage()"; }
  }
}    $test = new GamesSummery();
```

OUTPUT(S):

> "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\hockey\ganon.php on line 238"

OR

> "Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\hockey\ganon.php on line 19"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first: In php there are *fatal* errors, like syntax error (and others) which **cannot being catched**. The program will terminate immediately in this case.

---

For all other there is a way using [`set_error_handler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

I've prepared a custom error handler function for you that transforms all errors or warnings into exceptions. Note that the output of the function (the way I registered it) depends on the php.ini setting `error_reporting`.

First register the error handler:

```
set_error_handler('errorHandler', ini_get('error_reporting'));
```

Here comes the function itself:

```
function errorHandler(
            $errno,
            $errstr,
            $errfile = null,
            $errline = null,
            $errcontext = null
) {
    $message = sprintf("%s: %s, file: %s, line: %s",
        $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline
    );
    // -->
    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
```

---

You can try the code with the following example:

```
try {
   $a = 1 / 0; // will throw a warning
} catch ( Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Oh, so there are many different types of errors in PHP, and most of them are not Exceptions.

But there are others that simply cannot be caught? Does this count "Fatal error"s? Because, that is annoying. From my perspective I really do not care what happens in some called library, in this case and many others I can continue on execution pretty normally even if parsing failed. But not if I cannot catch the error.

Comment: I see their is another similar method for catching them as well.
I wonder if I can use the same function to catch both.

Comment: I don't understood the last comment. About fatal errors, if third party library triggers a fatal you have really a problem. That's like a segfault in C.

Comment: Oh, was just noting that: `register_shutdown_function( "fatal_handler" );
` exists.

Comment: Oh, yes you are right (I forgot) But note that `register_shutdown_function` is very limited. Most of object's will not being available anymore in `shutdown_function`. In other words, PHP is a fatal state and guarantees nothing anymore. The best thing you can (reliable) do is do a `echo 'fatal error: shutdown reached' ... No option to continue the program in a normal state

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski Years ago I've asked a related question on SO. answers may be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412676/how-to-let-apache-send-500-in-case-of-php-error

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be causing me all kinds of trouble.

Right now I have a testing script that outputs `Main: 2: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 18, file: C:\xampp\htdocs\hockey\phpQuery.php, line: 327` normally. If I take out your error handler, no error is produced and the expected result happens.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25821/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-jonathon-wisnoski)

Answer (score 2):

First, increase in your php.ini execution time, set_time_limit: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Second, your filename you are created is empty, so you need check or put a new filename:

You need create a filename or write a new filename before accessing it. Create a file as example:

> $ourFileName = "example";
>
> $ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
>
> fclose($ourFileHandle);

Answer (score 2):

- Converting (catchable) errors to exceptions: create a function which does this & use `set_error_handler()`.
- Preventing output from bad coders: use `ob_start()` & `ob_end_clean()`, but more to the point, try to find out where that coder lives and shit on his doorstep.
- People using `exit()` or `die()` in their libraries: dump the library immediately, there is no reason to have any trust in that code *at all*.

Unfortunately, fatal errors are often... fatal. No exceptions. But that's where we have `error_log` (on) & `display_errors` (off in production, on in dev) directives for.